# how to make dropdown field mandetory(i.e required) while entering in to database

Tags: php

> ```
>     <select name="location" id="category1" required>
>                                   <option value="location">Select City</option>
> <option value="anantapur>Anantapur</option>
> <option value="guntakal" required>Guntakal</option>
> <option value="guntur" required>Guntur</option>
> <option value="hyderabad" required>Hyderabad/Secunderabad</option>
> <option value="kakinada" required>kakinada</option>
> <option value="kurnool" required>kurnool</option>
> <option value="nellore" required>Nellore</option>
> <option value="nizamabad" required>Nizamabad</option>
> <option value="rajahmundry" required>Rajahmundry</option>
> <option value="tirupati" required>Tirupati</option>
> <option value="vijayawada" required>Vijayawada</option>
> <option value="visakhapatnam" required>Visakhapatnam</option>
> <option value="warangal" required>Warangal</option>
> </select>
> ```

how to make dropdown field mandetory(i.e required) while entering in to database

Comment: you can use jquery bootstrap validation, javascript validation, and also use \ php validation for dropdown field mandetory

Comment: change this: `<option value="">Select City</option>` then try to submit form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have already made dropdown field mandatory, the only thing you have to do is to set value for first option field empty, and mark it "selected" as default

i.e:

```
<option value="" selected>Select City</option>
```

this will prevent to submit your form until you select a value from dropdown.

That's it :)